Should I caulk the corner of my siding?
Background
During a recent storm (high rain, high wind) - my ceiling received some water damage:

Prior to the storm, there was a tiny bit of staining on the roof.  Maybe 3" long, and 3mm wide.
I suspected that my flat tpo roof may be to blame - so I contacted a roofer to come and assess the roof.  The roofer applied a couple patches to the roof, applied a bit of caulk but said that generally the roof was in good shape and didn't need to be replaced.
The roofer did mention that the siding on my house was older and could be the source of the water damage.
The roofer suggested that I caulk the vertical corner in my siding:


Questions

Does it make sense to caulk here?  My understanding was that the job of siding was to protect the water barrier underneath and siding didn't need to be perfectly water-tight.

Even if it is not necessary to caulk here, will doing so cause an issues?

It is possible that the patch the roofer did will solve the issue but he seemed somewhat uncertain if that was the source of the water infiltration.  If I want to get a professional inspection of the siding, who is the right person to call?  A general contractor?  Someone else?



Does water/rain flow off the top roof onto the bottom roof?  If no gutter/downsprout to divert the water, that might be an easier fix.

@crip659 - The main roof is also a flat roof that drains to the center but there is a small angled roof (11'x4') that drains to this roof.

While it would not hurt to caulk the outside corners, I'd be more curious about why there is caulking at the inside corner in picture 2. 1. That is not a standard joint detail for siding and 2. It's closer to where the water damage is.

I highly doubt caulking the corners of your siding will solve a leaky roof, which is almost certainly what is causing the ceiling staining.  Can you also provide some photos from futher away, so we can see your entire house/roof?
